# Build C++ program on Windows with CL (VS Build Tool Compiler)

Tags: c++, cmake, msbuild, cl

I try to build program from command line with CL.
Run next command:

```
CL -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" C:\dev\projects\console-interaction-tester\main.cpp
```

And I caught error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: ...... corecrt.h: No such file or directory

I tried all flags from VS ouptup, like **/nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes** but it doesn't work.

I need sample of command, what can ignore UniversalCRT, or instruction how fix path. I wanted to add includes dir with corecrt.h but classic location **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\includes** doesn't exists!

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows SDK.

Run the VS2017 installer again, and select it (or plainly select the full C++ dev package).

Comment: Is this only way? Have I install 16 Gb of sowf to compile little C++ program?

Comment: If smb interested, I installed another components for C++ dev and write bat file for build.

Solution here:

https://github.com/goforbroke1006/console-interaction-tester/blob/master/install.bat

Comment: Yes, it's the only way. You don't have to have the full package, then you have to go an look for the Windows SDK inside the individual models.